# Move Row from table 2 to table 1 when Column C cell has been filled

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking on some guidance on how to move Row from table 2 to table 1 when Column C cell has been filled. I'm fairly new to Excel/VBA and honestly, I'm quite lost on how to approach this.

[image: Move Row from Table 2 to 1]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Macro9()
' Macro9 Macro

    Range("C75").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "TASK34"
    Rows("75:75").Select
    Selection.Cut

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-92
    Range("Table2[[#Headers],[First_Name]]").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("Table2[[#Totals],[First_Name]]").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=16
    Rows("75:75").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro first when you do it manually? That's always a good place to start when you have no idea.

Comment: Thanks - I did actually! However, not sure how to address when Column C is filled with any data, to move the row. Rather that the data I entered in create the macro

Comment: Maybe include the section of the code in question to better understand it?

Comment: Thanks - I've included in the description above